# How can i edit a react-table input (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello fellow programmers.

Im new to react and i am trying to Update data inside `react-table` table.

I want to update the data in a particular cell with an `onClick()` event

following is my code snippet for code reference

```
return (
    <div>
        <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: 'solid 1px blue' }}>
        <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th
                    {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                    {column.render('Header')}
                </th>
                ))}
            </tr>
            ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                    return (
                    <td
                        {...cell.getCellProps()} onClick={() => console.log(cell.value)} >
                        {cell.render('Cell')}
                    </td>
                    )
                })}
                </tr>
            )
            })}
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: please add some more details to your question, codeReview required , for a start add some screenShot or CodePlay for your problem

Comment: i have edited the question im new to stack overflow sorry mate. :D

Comment: noWorry's welcome to the club, now in regard to your problem , do you want to update values of cell ?

Comment: Yes like just a simple update like hardcoded saying the value of the cell is "" for example and with the render part so that it shows the new value fo the cell

Comment: can you share your onClick function snnippt ?

Comment: i made another edit of the question for you. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: onClick={() => console.log(cell.value)} ?? here you have to update your originalState of data to initiate a render then it will reflect new data in next render PS: can you share your rows data  from which you are mapping

Comment: the rows and columns are defined above in variables. data holds 24 columns. in the onClick i say onClick={() => cell.value = ""} i have tried it with useState but couldnt make it work :/

Comment: we need to see a working example can you create a demo in jsfiddle and share , ill look it and try to help you out

Comment: im sorry but i cant make it work in jsfiddle. never used that before and copy pasting does not working apparently. ill just write it as good as i can. my file starts with the imports. normal stuff. then i have export default function Table() {} then im defining the data and column arrays which contain diffrent objects. the onClick function is like above the inline onClick after the ref={} property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make the table editable > you can try with following example , its self explanatory in their official docs.. check if it can help

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v7/examples/editable-data?file=/src/App.js:6709-6714

Comment: Thank you my friend this worked beautifully!!!!